# Detect if `connect()` has been invoked on TCP socket

Tags: python, sockets

If feel this should be incredibly obvious, but somehow I haven't found it in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

Consider this

```
import socket
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

How do I check if `connect()` has been called on `my_socket`. Currently my code sets a separate boolean in my class, but I believe it should be possible to ask the socket object about that. For clarification, I am writing client code and I want to provide some introspection in my classes to check if the socket has been connected to a server.

Something like

```
my_socket.is_connected()
=> False
my_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 42))
=> None
my_socket.is_connected()
=> True
```

Comment: Are you accepting connections anywhere?

Comment: No, I am connecting to a server.

Comment: If you're the client then you should be the one calling connect and other sockets should not be connecting to you.

Comment: I know what you mean. I am calling connect and I want a way to check if I have called `connect`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to call `getpeername()` and handle the resulting error or state if it isn't connected.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect if `connect` has been called, you can just subclass `socket.socket` like this:

```
class Sock(socket.socket):
    def connect(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().connect(*args, **kwargs)
        print("tried to connect!")
```

And then use `Sock` just like you'd use `socket.socket`:

```
my_socket = Sock(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Comment: I see - this was kinda the thing I would expect the standard API to provide.

Comment: @NielsB. Why? Java provides an `isConnected()` method, and it is all but useless. All it does is confuse people into thinking that if it returns true the *connection* is still connected, which it doesn't mean at all. Why doesn't your application already know where it is up to? Easy way out of that is to never create an unconnected socket. They're not much use.

Comment: I ended at the same conclusion. Set the socket instance variable to None until we are making a connection.